# Some Operator Expected in MQL5

Tags: mql5

Gday, I'm new to coding and I'm stuck on the error message in this screen shot. When I compile it says - Some Operator Expected. Please help! :)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njkiw.png)

I've checked all the syntax and spelling and rewatched the video I was following but can't seem to understan where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Post your code. Not just a picture of the code. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Given previous comments, check your code for missing semi-colons at the end of lines, I can see 2 missing straight away.